# Libraries / packages proper managing - setting paths

Tags: delphi, package, components, delphi-xe2

I have a bunch of custom packages which I have in one group project. For couple of hours I'm trying to set search/output paths properly. But even if compiled sources are in some path - it's not visible to other package (which needs it).

```
Required package 'PackageName' not found
```

or if it sees it

`Never-build package 'PackageName' must be recompiled` (of course recompiling does not help)

or

`Unable to install...` (ok, but why?)

I don't have any duplicated compiled sources which can be the problem.

What is the best way to manage those paths without any problems?

(already read [Build server: Best practices managing third party components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017023/build-server-best-practices-managing-third-party-components))